# Bug related to tf.sparse_tensor_dense_matmul()

Tags: tensorflow

**Example**
The following example has some bugs that I can not solve.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import scipy.sparse as sp
from scipy.sparse import csc_matrix

def sparse_to_tuple(sparse_mx):
    """Convert sparse matrix to tuple representation."""
    def to_tuple(mx):
        if not sp.isspmatrix_coo(mx):
            mx = mx.tocoo()
        coords = np.vstack((mx.row, mx.col)).transpose()
        values = mx.data
        shape = mx.shape
        return coords, values, shape

    if isinstance(sparse_mx, list):
        for i in range(len(sparse_mx)):
            sparse_mx[i] = to_tuple(sparse_mx[i])
    else:
        sparse_mx = to_tuple(sparse_mx)

    return sparse_mx

A = csc_matrix(np.diag(np.array([1, 2, 3])))
A = sparse_to_tuple(A)

B = tf.ones([3, 2], tf.float32)
C = tf.sparse_placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(3, 3))
D = tf.sparse_tensor_dense_matmul(C, B)

# if this line, together with the last line, is commented, it can run
H = tf.matmul(tf.sparse_tensor_dense_matmul(C, B), tf.transpose(B, [1, 0]))

with tf.Session() as sess:
    out = sess.run(D, {C: A})
    print('----------------')
    print(out)
    print('----------------')
    print(sess.run(H, {C: A}))
```

#### Error:

> ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
>
> ```
> <ipython-input-83-02386eb1014c> in <module>()
>      32 
>      33 with tf.Session() as sess:
> ---> 34     out = sess.run(D, {C: A})
>      35     print('----------------')
>      36     print(out)
> ```
>
> /usr/local/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in run(self, fetches, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
>
> ```
>     898     collected into this argument and passed back.
>     899 
> --> 900     Args:
>     901       fetches: A single graph element, a list of graph elements,
>     902         or a dictionary whose values are graph elements or lists of graph
> ```
>
> /usr/local/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in _run(self, handle, fetches, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
>
> ```
>    1111                 ' is not compatible with Tensor type ' + str(subfeed_dtype) +
>    1112                 '. Try explicitly setting the type of the feed tensor'
> -> 1113                 ' to a larger type (e.g. int64).')
>    1114 
>    1115           is_tensor_handle_feed = isinstance(subfeed_val,
> ```
>
> ValueError: Tensor Tensor("Const_132:0", shape=(2,), dtype=int64) may not be fed.

**System information**
tesorflow-gpu = 1.9.0
python = Python 3.6.5 :: Anaconda, Inc.
Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: It works well on my machine (tensorflow == 1.12.0).

Comment: Thanks Rvinas. It turns out that in my environment, there should be some modification of the code: C = tf.sparse_placeholder(tf.float32).